# Set environment variables from within a bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, shell-script

Is there a way to set environment variables from within a (bash) shell script?

I want to set some environment variables on some servers using a small script rather than typing. [Some forum posts believe it is impossible](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2005-05/msg01011.html).

Any Ideas?

Comment: see also: http://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-script/176788#176788

Answer (score 5, accepted):

file export_FOOBAR:

```
# set variable FOOBAR to "hi"
FOOBAR=hi
export FOOBAR
```

at the prompt

```
yourhost:/~ > source export_FOOBAR
```

Comment: Great. What dose 'source' mean?

Comment: type  "man source" in your shell

Comment: type "man <any_shell_command>" to find out what it does

Comment: I have none. It's probably part of bash - where can I find its docs?

Comment: type man bash and then look for the source command (within the bash man page search for 'SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS' and it is usually shortly after that)

Comment: Bash Reference Manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html (your really need to learn about google :-)

Comment: Good, but I wouldn't put #!/bin/bash (I assume that's what you meant) at the start of the script, as this script won't work if executed.

Comment: @Douglas Leeder : working from memory =&gt; errors, thx for the feedback

Comment: BTW: If "man <command>" does not work, b/c the command is built into bash ,you can use "help <command>" . That invokes bash's internal help :-).

Answer (score 1):

For Bash built-ins, use the built-in `help`.  E.g.:

```
$ help source
```

To see if a command will be handled by the shell (is a built-in), use the `type` bash built-in:

```
$ type help

$ type type
```