# How to change default vi alias in Fedora 14?

Tags: linux, bash, alias, bashrc, bash-alias

In my laptop, if I type below

```
$ which vi
alias vi='vim'
    /usr/bin/vim
```

Now I want to change the vi alias to another bin, e.g. `vim_wrapper` a script created in /usr/bin/, I type this line:

```
alias vi="vim_wrapper"
```

in `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bashrc`, but take no effects. So How to **change the default vi alias vi='vim' to vi='vim_wrapper'**? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aliases added to `bashrc` don't take effect immediately.  You have to restart your terminal session or logout and log back in.

To make the alias take effect immediately, run the alias line you added on a terminal as if it were a command or source your `bashrc` as Nitrodist explains in the first comment.

Comment: Not quite the same thing. You have to `source` the file (instead of running it with `~/bashrc` on its own), otherwise the changes will not be reflected in the terminal. So, either do `. ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @Nitrodist:  Out of curiosity, what is the difference?   Obviously your method is better if you add more than one alias or make other changes, but for just adding one alias you'd think both methods would have the same effect.

Comment: just executing the file does not make those changes available in your terminal. If I export a variable in the `.bashrc` and I execute the script instead of sourcing it, then that exported variable disappears after the script finishes executing. See http://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107808/what-happens-when-i-execute-a-unix-shell-script-using-a-command and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880735/difference-between-launching-a-script-with-script-sh-and-script-sh

Comment: @Nitrodist:  I meant run the `alias` command, but that wasn't very clear in my post.  I've updated it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to modify the original `vi` alias set. Here's my `grep` result:

```
/etc/profile.d/vim.sh: alias vi >/dev/null 2>&1 || alias vi=vim
```