# "history position out of range" when calling history from bash script

Tags: bash, command-history

I want to make a simple script to delete a line from `bash_history`, based on user input of the line number.

```
echo -n "Delete History Line Number: "
read num
history -d $num
```

The error is "history position out of range" (which it shouldn't be, I'm using a number within range).

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: A question like this would be answered on Stack Overflow, if you described the specific problem.

Comment: Are you getting an error output?  If so, what specifically?

Comment: The error is "history position out of range" (which it shouldn't be, I'm using a number within range)

Comment: You have to read bash's source to solve the riddle.

Comment: Why isn't this the appropriate place to ask this question? It's specific and brief and seems to meet all the guidelines listed here: http://superuser.com/about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two reasons why your script will not work as intended:

1. The bash environment for a running script is "non-interactive" and does not have the history features enabled.
2. The bash environment for a running script is independent from the environment you are interactively working in.

Depending on your use case the easiest solution might be to source the script, instead of executing. See [the SU post explaining the difference of sourcing and executing](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip/176788#176788) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Through the source method its working,

my *source_file.sh* contain

```
# cat /root/source_file.sh
#!/bin/bash
history -d $1
```

and my *master_file.sh* have below lines

```
# cat /root/master_file.sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
echo -e "Enter command number from history(syntax: source script_name.sh xxxx)"
else
source /root/source_file.sh && echo -e "Line number $1 removed successfully"
```

fi

we can test the script now,

```
# source /root/master_file.sh
Enter command number from history(syntax: source script_name.sh xxxx)
```

okay lets add the line number

```
# history | tail -n 10
 1193  grep disable /etc/sysconfig/selinux
 1194  grep enforce /etc/sysconfig/selinux
 1195  sestatus
 1196  arch
 1197  uname -r
 1198  uname -a
 1199  history
 1200  history | tail -n 10
 1201  pwd
 1202  history | tail -n 10
```

Lets remove the line 1196

```
# source /root/master_file.sh 1196
Line number 1196 removed successfully
```

```
# history | tail -n 10
 1194  grep enforce /etc/sysconfig/selinux
 1195  sestatus
 1196  uname -r
 1197  uname -a
 1198  history
 1199  history | tail -n 10
 1200  pwd
 1201  history | tail -n 10
 1202  source /root/master_file.sh 1196
 1203  history | tail -n 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If the 'history position out of range' occurs during a loop this solution might help:

The following command will invert the output of the history command:

```
history | tac
```

Use this in a for loop to remove all history command that contain "YOUR_SEARCHSTRING":

```
for ln in $( history | tac | grep "YOUR_SEARCHSTRING" | cut -f2 -d' '); do history -d $ln; done
```

Using 'tac' to revert history will avoid having 'out of range' errors.