# How do I identify shell script execution vs dot execution

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script, shell-script

I'm writing a bash script that needs to run on the current process for it to be useful.

That is, I want to make sure that the script was invoked with `source script.sh` or `. ./script.sh` and **not** `./script.sh`.

For those of you who don't know the difference refer to this:
[What is the difference between executing a Bash script vs sourcing it?](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip)

I know I can do `chmod u-x script.sh` so it can't be executed without sourcing, but users can may recognise it as a script and `chmod` it themselves. I would like a more elegant solution if one exists.

Is there a way for the script to recognise that it has not been invoked with `source` or `.` and exit with an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script is being sourced by `bash`, then `$0` is `bash` or `-bash`:

```
[[ $0 =~ ^-?bash$ ]] && echo "Thank you for sourcing me"
```

Alternatively, if you know that your script is called `script.sh` but you don't care what shell it might be sourced in, then invert the test:

```
[ "X$(basename -- "$0")" != "Xscript.sh" ] && echo "Thank you for sourcing me"
```

(Note that since the above is for general (POSIX) shells, it does not use `[[` tests.)

For more discussion of related issues, see [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850166/how-to-determine-if-a-shell-script-file-is-sourced-in-bash).