# bash: smart autocomplete based on history?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I once found an amazing bash option, but now I can't remember how to re-enable it.

It extended autocomplete to look at your most recent history. So if you'd previously typed `open index.html` and then `open map.html`, typing

```
$ op
```

and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> once would autocomplete to `open map.html`. Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> again would autocomplete to `open index.html`.

Does anyone know how I can re-enable this?

Comment: refer to [bash history search](https://askubuntu.com/a/59855/582516)

Answer (score 48):

Run in your bash:

```
cat >> ~/.inputrc <<'EOF'
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
EOF
```

Open a new shell session, or just reload inputrc:

```
bind -f  ~/.inputrc
```

Now use <kbd>⬆</kbd> and <kbd>⬇</kbd> after entering the beginning of the command - it will auto-complete from history.

Comment: Note: this broke by "c" key in terminals on OSX for me.

Comment: thank you so much, been looking for this for some time now :)

Comment: Amazing I've been looking for this for a while!

Answer (score 12):

According to [this page](http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/01/28/turn-on-bash-smart-completion/) ("Turn on Bash Smart Completion") on Ubuntu Blog, it is as easy as editing your `bash.bashrc` file. For clarity, I rewrote these instructions below in a more beginner-friendly manner.

## Instructions (Linux)

1. From a terminal window, edit your system's `bash.bashrc` file. To do this with a command-line text editor like [nano](http://www.nano-editor.org/), execute the command `sudo nano /etc/bash.bashrc` (and if needed, enter your password).
2. Use the arrow keys to find these lines:

   ```
   #if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
   #   . /etc/bash_completion
   #fi
   ```
3. Un-comment each of these lines (by removing the `#` prefix that each line has).
4. Save the file (you do this in nano by pushing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to quit), and it should now work. *Please note: for the changes to take effect in existing terminals, `/etc/bash.bashrc` will need to be [sourced](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-script). Alternatively, logout and login again, or just reboot.*

To disable it, all you need to do is re-comment each of the lines above (by adding a `#` to the start of each line).

Presumably, the above will also work (for your user account)
if you insert the above three lines, minus their `#` characters,
into your personal `.bashrc` file. If you do that,
you won't need to use `sudo`.

---

According to [this blog post](http://blog.jeffterrace.com/2012/09/bash-completion-for-mac-os-x.html) ("Bash Completion for Mac OS X"), the instructions are different for Mac OS X. Here is what you need to do.

## Instructions (Mac OS X)

1. Make sure you have [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) installed, and then use it to install the package `bash-completion` (by typing the command `brew install bash-completion`).
2. Homebrew should now tell you what you need to do to complete the installation. In this case, you need to add these three lines to your `.bashrc` file (using either a command-line text editor like nano which we used above, or a graphical one):

   ```
   if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
      . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
   fi
   ```
3. You should now have auto-completion in bash. *Please note: for the changes to take effect in existing shells, `.bashrc` will need to be [sourced](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-script). Alternatively, logout and login again, or just reboot.*

To disable it, all you need to do is remove the lines we added above, and run the command `brew uninstall bash-completion --force`.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm actually using OSX and there is an `/etc/bashrc` file, but it doesn't have those lines. I've added them anyway, but there's no `/etc/bash_completion` file either, so I'm not sure they're doing anything...

Comment: @flossfan I just added instructions for Mac OSX.

Answer (score 10):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, so I am adding an answer
In Ubuntu 18.04, this is what I did (to get auto completion on up and down arrows at shell)

- edited ~/.bashrc
- added these two lines (towards the end)

```
bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[B": history-search-forward'
```

- reloaded bash; (or get out of terminal and come back in)

Comment: Note that this is exactly the same solution as @Noam Manos, you're simply configuirng Readline via `bind` commands in your bashrc instead of simply configuring Readline directly (with `~/.inputrc`)