# I changed my "HOME" variable and now cannot find "~/.bash_profile" to change it back

Tags: bash, mac, environment-variables

I was messing around with environment variables on my Mac, trying to learn how to use them and I used the command `nano ~/.bash_profile` where I then added the line `HOME=/Users/MyCompName/Desktop` to update my home variable.

This change worked and can be seen when I use `printenv` to view all environment variables but when I went to change `HOME` back I couldn't seem to find `~/.bash_profile` anymore. Where did it go?

Comment: Basically `~` means `$HOME`

Comment: ...so if you redefine `$HOME`, `~`gets redefined too

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's in the same place.

Before the change `~` expands to something like `/Users/YourUserName`, the shell finds your `.bash_profile` there. After the file gets sourced `~` expands to another path so `~/.bash_profile` no longer points to the relevant file. This is because in this context `~` means `$HOME`.

If you know the full path to your actual home directory, you can use it instead of `~`. In Mac it would probably look like this:

```
nano /Users/YourUserName/.bash_profile
```

Or let your Bash look up your home directory in the user database rather than just looking at `$HOME`. This doesn't require you to remember anything:

```
nano ~YourUserName/.bash_profile
```

Modifying your `HOME` variable without changing your actual home directory is not the best idea. Changing any user's home directory is an administrative task, usually regular users cannot do this.

Comment: Awesome I was able to find it again thanks! Would you mind elaborating on what you mean by "after the file gets sourced"? I'm unfamiliar with what it means for a file to get sourced

Comment: @Matt `.bash_profile` has a form of a Bash script. You can run a script or source it. Running means creating a subshell and executing the script line by line there. Sourcing means executing the script in the *current* shell. Some tasks that are meant to affect the current shell cannot be executed in a subshell; changing a variable for the current shell is one of them. That's why some files are sourced, not executed in a subshell. To manually source a file use `. file` (`.` is specified by POSIX) or `source file` (`source` is a non-POSIX extension understood by few shells).

Comment: @Matt See this: [What is the difference between executing a Bash script vs sourcing it?](https://superuser.com/q/176783/432690)

Comment: If you(Matt) don't know where your home directory used to be, you can use `nano ~YourUserName/.bash_profile` instead. This will look up your home directory in the user database rather than just looking at $HOME.

Comment: @StigHemmer The answer is now community wiki. Your useful comment has been assimilated. Thank you.