# Why are ssh-agent and ssh-add not working together in one bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, shell, arch-linux

I wrote one script where I would like it to start the `ssh-agent` first in order to run the agent in background, and set the appropriate environment variables for the current shell instance. However, in second part of the script I would also like to add my private SSH key in order to connect to my server.

Currently, neither command in the script is working with each other. Can someone help me properly understand what I am doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

exec ssh-agent bash
sleep 5s
ssh-add /media/MyUSB/.ssh/id_00123 &
```

In addition, while utilizing the built-in debugger on `bash` I can see that only the first section of the script is working (i.e. `exec ssh-agent bash`).

Answer (score 2):

So many interesting aspects in such a small script.

---

#### Understanding `ssh-agent`

Let's start from what `ssh-agent` is designed to do. You run `ssh-agent` when you want a process that sits there, listens on some socket (it's a type of [file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690) for two-way interprocess communication) and serves requests from programs like `ssh-add` or `ssh` that connect to the socket. Programs will talk to the agent and store, manipulate or use private keys.

Any program that wants to use an agent needs to know the path to the socket the agent listens on. If a program knows the path then it can use the socket to communicate with the agent.

A design decision was once made: any program that wants to know the path to the socket of an authentication agent should check the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable in its own environment, the value of the variable is the path. It was a decision (I mean things could be designed in some other way, e.g. programs might be designed to accept this path via command-line arguments each time), but it was a very good decision.

It was a very good decision because the environment is by default inherited. This means you need to set the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable for one process (e.g. a shell) and all its descendants will inherit it (unless some of them deliberately choose to alter their environment or to create a child with altered environment). For comparison: passing the path as a command-line argument each time you want to run something that should talk to the agent requires extra typing; and you would want to store the path somewhere, so probably in a variable anyway. So here you go, the name of the variable is standardized and interested programs check it automatically.

Another option was to store the path in a text file in a fixed location, or even to create a socket in a fixed location in the first place. But sometimes you want some programs to use one agent (one socket) and some other programs to use another agent (another socket). Making two programs see different files in the same location is hard. Making two programs see different environment variables is easy.

So, interested programs should check `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in their environment. How can we or anything set this variable to the right value in the environment of a process? Without a debugger there are two ways:

1. Either the parent knows the value and when it spawns a child it sets up `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` with the right value in the environment for the child (an act of inheriting unchanged `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` from the parent may be interpreted as "the parent setting this up by doing nothing");
2. or the process learns the value in some other way and modifies its own environment.

Therefore `ssh-agent` supports two methods of starting it:

1. ```
   ssh-agent command …
   ```

   Here `ssh-agent` creates a socket and prepares itself to serve future programs connecting to the socket. Then it runs `command …` as its child with `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` with the right value in the environment for the child. The child (or any descendant that inherits the variable) can easily find the socket, but other processes not so easily. When the `command` terminates, so does `ssh-agent` (even if there are grandchildren).
2. ```
   ssh-agent   # but don't use it exactly this way
   ```

   Here `ssh-agent` forks to the background, i.e. it creates a child copy of itself and does not wait for it to exit. The child detaches from standard streams of the parent and from the terminal, it will not exit by itself. The child will be the real agent that will stay. The parent will exit by itself, but before it happens, shell code is printed. The shell code, when evaluated by a shell, makes the shell modify its own environment, so `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` with the right value is put there. [But the shell has to *evaluate* the output, not just run `ssh-agent`](https://superuser.com/q/1734785/432690), so the right way is like:

   ```
   eval "$(ssh-agent)"
   ```

   After this the shell that run `eval` has the right variable (in fact: variables) in its environment and from now on commands like `ssh-add` run from this shell will find the agent because they will inherit the variable. Exiting the shell does not terminate the agent, so at some point before exiting the shell you may want to invoke `ssh-agent -k` (or, if you also want to unset the variables: `eval "$(ssh-agent -k)"`). An agent for which there is no process holding the right value of `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is virtually useless.

---

#### What is wrong with your script

And now – finally – to your script. This is your script:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> exec ssh-agent bash
> sleep 5s
> ssh-add /media/MyUSB/.ssh/id_00123 &
> ```

The first thing the script does is `exec ssh-agent bash`. `exec` tells the shell interpreting the script to replace itself with the command, which is `ssh-agent bash`. The shell does it and becomes `ssh-agent` that starts a new `bash` (it's the method 1 from above). This `bash` holds the right value of `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, it is interactive, it prints a prompt and allows you to run commands (including commands that need `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`). If your original interactive shell was `bash` then you may miss the fact you're now in a separate `bash`. You may interpret the existence of `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` as confirmation that `ssh-agent` has modified the environment of your original shell. No, you're still in the middle of your script.

Well, not exactly in the middle. If you exit this `bash`, then `sleep` and the rest won't be executed, because the shell interpreting the script has replaced itself with `ssh-agent`. In some sense you're one `exit` before the end of the script.

If your method to run the script was like `./myscript`, then `exit` will put you back in the original shell. If your method was like [`. ./myscript` or `source myscript`](https://superuser.com/q/176783/432690) then `exit` will act as if you exited the original shell, because the original shell was the shell interpreting the script and has replaced itself with `ssh-agent` that is about to exit upon your `exit` from the current shell; this can strengthen the impression you were in (and now you are exiting) the original shell.

---

#### The fix

In the question you have explicitly stated your goal:

> […] appropriate environment variables for the current shell instance. […]

To modify the environment of the current shell, the script has to use the method 2 from above. The current shell has to be the interpreting shell, i.e. the script has to be sourced. The shell mustn't `exec` to anything, as you don't want the shell to be replaced by anything. Example fix:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/false
[ -n "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || eval "$(ssh-agent)"
ssh-add /media/MyUSB/.ssh/id_00123
```

There's more what has been improved:

- `#!/usr/bin/false` as the shebang ensures the script will do nothing and fail if you (inadvertently) run it instead of sourcing it. Other strategies are here: [*Strategy for forgetting to run a script with `source`*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/442110/108618). [Without a shebang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373223/108618) or with a shebang pointing to `bash`, `sh` or another compatible shell, the script executed (not sourced) would start a new agent, add the key to it and exit. All this without affecting the environment of your current shell, so the agent would sit there in vain, almost inaccessible. You would need to put some effort in finding and killing it, or some effort in finding its socket and manually setting `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in the environment of your shell; or you would just let it be. `false` as the shebang prevents this inconvenient scenario.
- `[ -n "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]` checks if `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` expands to a non-empty string. An empty string indicates there is no agent available, while a non-empty string indicates there is probably an agent. The script starts a new `ssh-agent` only if the string is empty. This is a basic precaution against a scenario where you (inadvertently) source the script for the second time, create a new authentication agent and lose variables associated with the previous agent that will keep running uselessly.
- There's no need to `sleep`. `ssh-agent` in our script exits when the agent (i.e. its child in the background) is ready. You can `ssh-add` right away.
- `ssh-add` is here as a synchronous command. Running it asynchronously (with `&`, like you tried to do) is probably not going to save you a lot of time. You can try. But you will most likely source the script from an interactive shell with job control enabled and thus `&` (if you put it there) will pollute your terminal with a message like `[1]+  Done …`.