# ssh-agent don't keep my keys configured

Tags: linux, ssh, git

Every time I need to use git pull, I need to run `ps aux | grep ssh`, kill all ssh process, included `ssh-agent`, and then I type the commands `` eval `ssh-agent` ``   and `ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_key`. The configuration is not being maintained. (I have two keys generated, the first one is working well and the second one have this problem).

Comment: "The configuration is not being maintained" – What do you mean? Not maintained across reboot? or from shell to shell? or within the same agent? See the beginning of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1735329/432690). `ssh` seeks for a key in few default locations, an agent is not required for this; so if one of your keys is exactly there then it will work without access to any agent. What are the exact paths to the keys? Do not respond in comments, [edit] the question and add information there.

Comment: It is not maintained across reboot!

Answer (score 2):

I found that I need to tell the ssh-agent what is the key when handling connections like `github.com` or any other. if you have remote (`git remote -v`) like `git@github.com:path/to/file.git`, you should create a ssh config file in the path `~/.ssh/config` with the following configuration

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<github_private_key>
```

Where the `github_private_key` is your private private key that you want to bind with the `github.com` remote. the `Host` configuration is an alias for the configuration, i am using the alias equal to the `HostName` because of my already configured remote.
In general case, if you have a remote like `user@host:path/to/file.git`
and you are configuring the connection with github, the configuration should have this content

```
Host <host>
    HostName github.com
    User <user>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<github_private_key>
```

To have this configuration in a best way, you can create a new configuration on `~/.ssh/config` file like this

```
Host my-alias
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<github_private_key>
```

Now, instead using `git clone git@github.com:path/to/file.git` you can use `git clone git@my-alias:path/to/file.git`
If you have the git repository already cloned, you can change you remote to `git@my-alias:path/to/file.git`.

Comment: `ssh-agent` does not read `~/.ssh/config`. `ssh` does, regardless if an agent is running or not.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, thanks for the correction