# SSH agent will not start on login

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, manjaro, ssh-agent

I've got an issue where ssh-agent does not start automatically on login. I have tried writing a service, configuring a systemd autostart script and a bunch of other things.

Another thing I've noticed, is that even if I run `eval $(ssh-agent -s)`, the agent will only work until I restart the terminal. Closing and opening the terminal again, then running `ssh-add -l` gives the dreaded `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.` message.

The service that I wrote, with some guidance, looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=SSH agent (ssh-agent)

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/ssh-agent.socket"
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
ExecStart=ssh-agent -D -a $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
ExecStop=kill -15 $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

However, it doesn't work, despite starting and running successfully. Here's the `systemctl` output:

```
>> systemctl --user status ssh-agent
● ssh-agent.service - SSH agent (ssh-agent)
     Loaded: loaded (/home/david/.config/systemd/user/ssh-agent.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-01-30 20:08:14 GMT; 9min ago
    Process: 10959 ExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 10958 (ssh-agent)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18864)
     Memory: 840.0K
        CPU: 8ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/ssh-agent.service
             └─10958 ssh-agent -D -a /run/user/1000/ssh-agent.socket

Jan 30 20:08:11 pleb-box systemd[839]: Starting SSH agent (ssh-agent)...
Jan 30 20:08:11 pleb-box ssh-agent[10958]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/ssh-agent.socket; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
Jan 30 20:08:11 pleb-box ssh-agent[10958]: echo Agent pid 10958;
Jan 30 20:08:14 pleb-box systemd[839]: Started SSH agent (ssh-agent).

>> echo $SSH_AGENT_PID


>> echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK


>> ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

As you can see, it doesn't even export the two environment variables, despite it being the second log line. Trying to `echo` them, returns empty values.
I use zsh, but this happens on bash too.

Here's some of my system information:

```
>> uname -a
Linux pleb-box 5.15.89-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jan 18 20:37:11 UTC 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux

>> zsh --version
zsh 5.9 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

>> konsole --version
konsole 22.12.1

>> systemctl --version
systemd 252 (252.4-2-manjaro)
+PAM +AUDIT -SELINUX -APPARMOR -IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS +FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY +P11KIT -QRENCODE +TPM2 +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD +BPF_FRAMEWORK +XKBCOMMON +UTMP -SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified

>> ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_9.1p1, OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ssh-agent` isn't supposed to start at boot. Rather, it's supposed to be an early process leader when you log in so that it can make `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `$SSH_AGENT_PID` available to processes via the environment

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't explain why it doesn't start at all, or doesn't persist between terminal sessions.

Comment: I think the agent does start but it forks to the background and the parent dies, so `Type=simple` makes systemd think the relevant process exited. The agent does persist between terminal sessions, the variables don't; they are important. Please see the first part of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1735329/432690).

Comment: @ThatGuy putting ssh agent into systemd means that none of your terminal sessions can benefit from it

Comment: Why systemd for such thing?

Comment: It appears to be a common recommendation by various people on and off SE. Presumably, since `ssh-agent` attempts to export variables, they should remain in the environment, not just get dumped once the terminal session is killed. It seems that manually exporting the variables in a new terminal session works fine.