# Why do I need to type in my password when using git?

Tags: ssh, git

This is a strange thing, but when I am physically opening a terminal at a computer, I can use git without any need to type in passwords.

For some reason, when I ssh to the machine (it is a Mini Mac), whenever I want to use git, I need to enter user name and password.

This is true for all git repos -- no matter which server they are located at (so it is not just gitlab, but also gitlab).

How can I make sure I don't need to type my password even when sshing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-can-i-save-username-and-password-in-git

Comment: You need to setup ssh with your git

Comment: I think this post wasn't read carefully - my git tokens are set properly, when I am on a Terminal physically on the computer, I don't need to type in user name and password. But when I ssh to the machine, I do, and I don't understand what setting is not "loaded" or how to make sure it is loaded. I tried to "source" on all my login files, and it doesn't help.

Comment: If you click the link I posted above it says: "You can also authenticate via SSH: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password"

Comment: @Gantendo I am not talking about authenticating via SSH to the git repo. I am talking about not being able to authenticate automatically into git when *I ssh into the machine*. Not related to the git repo. When I connect to my machine remotely using ssh, git requires password/usernames. Somehow, it ignores my ssh keys, or something.

Comment: "so it is not just gitlab, but also gitlab" – Huh?

Comment: I know nothing about Git or git\* services, but is it possible you use some key(s) automatically loaded into some agent (e.g. started by your desktop environment and available to any program started from the desktop)? When you ssh in, the agent either is not there, or you cannot access it. *If this is the case* then please see the first part of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1735329/432690) to get some insight.